# Проблема с импортом ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

в каталоге есть две папки , я из одной из них хочу импортировать файл в файл другой папки
Нашел вот такой способ, но он мне не нравится , так как тут указываю полный путь а не относительный .

```
sys.path.insert(1,'/home/taurus/news_projects/dolfin_anty/superful')
import interaction_profiles  as inter_p
```

Подскажите пожалуйста , как это можно обойти

Comment: ну постройте полный путь из относительного (в примитиве `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')`) и будет вам относительность.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я надеялся что есть какое то изящное решение